# How can I recursively scan for folders using `IF NOT EXIST`?

Tags: windows, batch

I want to make a batch script that will recursively search for specified directories using `IF NOT EXIST` to throw an error if the folders can't be located anywhere. Here is what I have so far:

```
IF NOT EXIST %FOLDER1% goto :ERROR
IF NOT EXIST %FOLDER2% goto :ERROR
IF NOT EXIST %FOLDER3% goto :ERROR

:ERROR
echo There aren't any folders to clean...
PAUSE goto :END
goto END
```

I will be replacing `%FOLDER1%`, `%FOLDER2%`, `%FOLDER3%` with different names depending on the circumstances and what folders need to be cleaned. It would appear that my current script only searches for files, how should I define directories with this syntax?

Comment: `IF NOT EXIST` matches folder too. Appears to me that there's a problem with the logic of your script - `:ERROR` is always run.  Try to add two lines `echo All Folders Exist` and `goto END`, after `IF NOT EXIST %FOLDER3% goto :ERROR` and before `:ERROR`.  Does it fix your problem?

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect _(if I understand your method correctly)_. I used quotes for folders with namespaces, and I double checked the syntax. The script runs the exact same this way...

Comment: If you want to do something recursively you're going to need a loop or command that does it for you. Currently you're just checking whenever one of the items exists. What @KennethL is pointing out, is that regardless of whenever or not they do, you will be outputting "There aren't any folders to clean". His edit would mean you'd skip from "Line 4" to the end.

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli Can you include sample inputs, e.g. how you run the batch file, and your folder structure, your current output and your expected output etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've included an easy way for you to do this and maintain the list of folders within the same script so you can make changes as needed by opening the script and modifying it accordingly.

Essentially this will [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) the `:List` subroutine which will contain the `Arrary` variable and it's values separated by commas and enclosed by double quotes for each folder path you want to check. It will then `GOTO :EOF` passing control back to the original `CALL` and then with a simple [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop you can iterate the `%Array%` variable values one by one against the `IF NOT EXIST` logic.

```
@ECHO ON

CALL :List
FOR %%A IN (%Array%) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%%~A" ECHO %%~A Does Not Exist
)
EXIT 

:List
::: Maintain your folder paths in the 'SET Array=' as values enclosed by double quotes and separated by commas
SET Array="C:\Folder\Path1", "X:\\Folder\\Math2", "\\server\Bath3", "c:/Folder/Wrath4"
GOTO :EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- [For](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Goto](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [Exit](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)